# Regex match first letter of words, but not "and"

Tags: regex

How would I write a regex that matches the first letter of each word (going to be capitalising them via PHP), but not the word "and".

So far I have:

```
/\b([a-z])/ig
```

This works for matching the first letter of words, but obviously not including anything yet for not matching where the word is "and".

Comment: In PHP PCRE, you can use [`'~\band\b(*SKIP)(*F)|\b\p{Ll}~u'`](https://regex101.com/r/zO6xN6/1), too (added `/u` just in case Unicode letters are to be handled, too).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a negative lookahead for this:

```
/\b(?!and\b)[a-z]/
```

Negative lookahead `(?!and\b)` before `\b[a-z]` will allow matching all words starting with lowercase English alphabet except `and`.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jI8jK2/2)